# How to modify XML file in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

```
<Customers>
  <Customer1>
    <Name>Bobby</Name>
    <Age>21</Age>
    <Address>Panjim</Address>
  </Customer1>
  <Customer2>
    <Name>Peter</Name>
    <Age>32</Age>
    <Address>Panjim</Address>
  </Customer2>
  <Customer4>
    <Name>Joel</Name>
    <Age>32</Age>
    <Address>Mapusa</Address>
  </Customer4>
</Customers>
```

So the thing is I want to delete a particular element and when i delete the first element i.e customer1, I want to update the other elements. I mean I want to make customer3, customer2 and customer2, customer1.
Can anyone please help me achieve this?

Comment: Wouldn't it make life easier if structure was <customers><customer /><customer /><customers> then you just remove the node you want?

Comment: Do the elements have to remain in the same order?

Comment: @RuneFS They don't have to be in the same order.

Comment: Thankyou everyone for the answers. I got my problem solved by changing the Xml structure. Thanks again.

Comment: @maestrosan11 No problem. Could you mark the best reply as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd argue that your problem is not how you could rename your nodes with minimum effort but  structure of your XML file.

You said order of customers is not important and apparently customer tag's number is not important, either, since you want to rename the tags upon deletion.

So maybe this structure just creates unnecessary complexity and extra work for you.

Only reason I see you could need the number in tag is to identify the node you are about to remove. Am I right or is there something more to it? If not then you could add random unique identifier (like Guid) to your customer data to remove the right one.

Could save you lot of trouble.

```
<customers>
    <customer>
        <guid>07fb-877c-...</guid>
        <name>Notch</name>
        <age>34</age>
        <address>street</address>
    </customer>
    <customer>
        <guid>1435-435a-...</guid>
        <name>Sam</name>
        <age>23</age>
        <address>other</address>
    </customer>
<customers>
```

Answer (score 3):

What about:

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[ ] args) {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("D:\\file.xml"); //example file
        doc.Root.SwitchAndRemove("Customer1");
        doc.Save("D:\\file.xml");
    }
}

public static class Utilities {
    public static void SwitchAndRemove(this XElement customers, XName name) {
        var x = customers.Descendants().Where(e => e.Name == name).Select((element, index) => new { element, index }).Single();

        int count = 0;
        XElement temp = x.element;
        foreach (XElement el in customers.Nodes()) {
            if (count == x.index + 1) {
                temp.RemoveAll();
                temp.Add(el.Descendants().ToArray());
                temp = el;
            }
            else
                count++;
        }

        temp.Remove();
    }
}
```

By giving as input your xml the output is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Customers>
  <Customer1>
    <Name>Peter</Name>
    <Age>32</Age>
    <Address>Panjim</Address>
  </Customer1>
  <Customer2>
    <Name>Joel</Name>
    <Age>32</Age>
    <Address>Mapusa</Address>
  </Customer2>
</Customers>
```

Answer (score 0):

Say the element you have to delete is Customer1, first of all you can read the complete xml file using one of the XML parsing classes available in c# like XDocument or XmlReader and write to another xml file say "Temp.xml" skipping the Customer1 element completely. This way we have achieved the deletion part.

Next to update, forget the file being XML file and read the entire file to a string, say "xmlstring". Now use the Replace function available with a string data type to replace "Customer2" with "Customer1" and then "Customer3" with "Customer2" and so on.

And now delete your original XML file and write the string "xmlstring" using a stream writer to a file name "YourFileName.xml"

Thats it. Hope this solution works for you. Try this and in case u are unable get this done, share the code which u tried and we shall suggest how to work it out.

Answer (score 0):

taken from your comment that the order does not have to be preserved then you can do this

```
public static void RemoveCustomer(XElement customers, XElement removeThis){

   var last = customeers.Elements().Last();
   if(last != removeThis){
       foreach(var element in removeThis.Elements()){
            element.Value = last.Element(element.Name).Value;
       }
   }
   last.Remove();
}
```

It effectively substitutes the one to be removed with the last (unless the last should be removed) and thereby eliminates the need for renaming any of the other elements